# Reciting 2 surah

Tags: salat

Slaam after I recite surah Al fatiha I recite surah ikhlas then surah falq do I say bismillah after I finish surah ikhlas to recite surah falq thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and how many times should we recite Bismillah in salah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38652/when-and-how-many-times-should-we-recite-bismillah-in-salah)